# Using a dictionary to determine when 4 processes are concurrently on

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

For a script I am writing I am given a dictionary such as:

```
Proc_rundict = {Proc1:[Intervals], Proc2:[intervals], Proc3:[Intervals], Proc4:[intervals]}
```

I need to determine when all 4 processes are  on, 3 of the processes are on, 2 of the processes are on and then only 1 of the process is on. The problem is that the intervals are not strictly uniform, and I am just stumped on how to attempt on solving this.

Intervals can be like:

```
[[2.4565,2.5678],[2.7635,2.8898],...]
```

Any help on this problem would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find each start time and each end time, sort them, and split your time into those subintervals. Then, for each subinterval, you can count how many processes are running.

```
times = []
for proc, intervals in Proc_rundict.items():
    for start, end in intervals:
        times.append(start)
        times.append(end)

sorted_times = sorted(times)
for i in range(1, len(sorted_times):
    start, end = sorted_times[i-1:i]
    running_this_interval = min(check_procs(start, Proc_dict), check_procs(end, Proc_dict))
```

(Assuming check_procs from Joran Beasley's answer, copied below)

```
def check_procs(curr_time, proc_dict):
    running = []
    for key, intervals in proc_dict.items():
        for start, end in intervals:
            if start<=curr_time<=end:
                running.append(key)
                break
    return running
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_procs(curr_time, proc_dict):
    running = []
    for key, intervals in proc_dict.items():
          for start, end in intervals:
              if start<=curr_time<=end:
                   running.append(key)
                   break
    return running
```

is probably how I would do it ...

Comment: ooh this helps alot but What curr_time should I choose to iterate through my dictionary with? (I was thinking the end of each interval from process 1, but then I am still left with alot of intervals for the other processes and some bits of intervals that are not completely contained in the proc1 interval)